# Avoid creation of Plone's default content

Tags: plone, genericsetup

I'm working in a project that creates a Plone 4.3 site that installs plone.app.contenttypes as it's default content types. After site creation I see all default content (the front page and some folders and collections) that are still Archetypes-based content.

I want to avoid the creation of that content and I want to know if there's a better way of getting rid of it that manually erasing it in a post install step.

I need an empty site by default.

Comment: Default contents are created by a generic setup step somewhere (in "plone-final" I think).

Probably the simple way is to delete such contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to setup the Plone Site the following way:

```
from Products.CMFPlone.factory import addPloneSite
from Products.CMFPlone.factory import _DEFAULT_PROFILE


default_profiles =('plonetheme.classic:default', 'plonetheme.sunburst:default')

return addPloneSite(
    app,
    site_id,
    title=title,
    profile_id=_DEFAULT_PROFILE,
    extension_ids=default_profiles,
    setup_content=False,
    default_language='en')
```

The important part is `setup_content=False`.

There's no initial content, no portlet...  nothing.

You may check this full working example in `ftw.inflator` -> https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.inflator/blob/00b8b984e7dc1052a7fb94d2e82455a66b271da7/ftw/inflator/bundle.py#L23

Comment: wow! that package seems all I need to solve my problems, thanks! just another question: is there another way to override default site creation process besides installing ftw.inflator? do I need to patch Plone? where?

Comment: You're welcome! AFAIK not, that's why the package provides a new button, below the original Plone Site creation button.

Comment: in fact there's a way to override the default behavior using [z3c.unconfigure](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.unconfigure) as you can see in [this package](https://github.com/plonegovbr/brasil.gov.portal/blob/master/src/brasil/gov/portal/browser/plone/overrides.zcml); maybe you can add that hack to ftw.inflator as the cherry on the cake.

Comment: @hvelarde Thank you very much for the hint, I opened a proposal/issue!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of patching Plone to achieve this behavior by default.

One is by using [z3c.jbot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot) to override the following template:

```
Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/plone-addsite.pt
```

The other is by using [collective.recipe.patch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.patch) in your Buildout configuration like this:

```
parts += patches
...
[patches]
recipe = collective.recipe.patch
egg = Products.CMFPlone==4.3.10
patches = ${buildout:directory}/patches/setup-content-false.patch
```

the content of the patch file is this (I would love to know how to get this without having to edit the output of the `git diff` command):

```
diff --git Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/plone-addsite.pt Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/plone-addsite.pt
index bc83eb0..3aebbfe 100644
--- Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/plone-addsite.pt
+++ Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/plone-addsite.pt
@@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
         </span>
       </div>
       <tal:content tal:condition="not:advanced">
-        <input type="hidden" name="setup_content:boolean" value="true" />
+        <input type="hidden" name="setup_content:boolean" />
       </tal:content>

       <tal:baseprofile condition="python: len(base_profiles) > 1">
```